# Fail upload sketches to ESP8266 only on Ubunto 20.04.3

Tags: serial, usb

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04, and Arduino IDE1.8.16. At the beginning adding user to `dialout` group enabled uploading sketch to Aruino AVR family, and ESP32, but still ESP8266 gives this error:

```
Sketch uses 260889 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 27980 bytes (34%) of dynamic memory, leaving 53940 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guy/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/upload.py", line 66, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "/home/guy/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 3552, in main
    esp.connect(args.before, args.connect_attempts)
  File "/home/guy/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 529, in connect
    raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

So I tried to erase flash using `esptool.py` :

```
guy@desktop:~$ esptool --chip  auto --port /dev/ttyUSB0 erase_flash
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to Espressif device: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

Since AVR's and ESP32 work properly using USB's and ACM's I can guess that is is not a problem with the ability to access serial comm.

What might it be ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something wrong with some new kernels of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, interfering with ESP8266 core uploading process

`5.4.0-88-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I had the same issue and downgraded the kernel to

`5.4.0-86-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 19:19:40 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

solved the issue

---

---

The issue happens to ESP8266 core uploading process, with the following tested Ubuntu cores

- `linux-5.11.0-37-generic`
- `linux-5.4.0-89-generic`
- `linux-5.4.0-88-generic`

and tested OK with

- `linux-5.11.0-38-generic`
- `linux-5.11.0-36-generic`
- `linux-5.8.0-48-generic`
- `linux-5.4.0-90-generic`
- `linux-5.4.0-86-generic`

---

#### Temporarily fix

To temporarily fix the issue by using working kernel, e.g. `linux-5.4.0-86-generic`

A. Select from GNU GRUB boot menu

- Advanced options for Ubuntu

  - Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-86-generic
- If you don't have that kernel, install by

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.4.0-86-generic
```

- Reboot and select `5.4.0-86-generic` from GNU GRUB boot menu

---

---

#### To save the selected GRUB settings

More info [**GRUB Simple-configuration**](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration)

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` by

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

2. Add to the file

```
 GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
 GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

3. Activate the change so that last selected value is used for the next boot.

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

#### Update

Just testing OK with latest kernel

- `linux-5.11.0-38-generic`
- `linux-5.4.0-90-generic`

It seems recent kernel release has fixed the issue