# ESP8266 - Can't upload or use Serial Monitor - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: arduino-ide, ubuntu, feather

When trying to use the ESP8266 Node MCU or Multiple Feather Huzzah's I get the following error. I can program Arduino Uno & Mega without issue.

```
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

I have tried all the many fixes on the web, the real issue is that all of these devices work fine with a windows machine. Also I use VMM and QEMU, I built a Windows 10 VM and Ubuntu 20.04 - When I share ttyS0 with either of these VM's I can program the 8266 just fine, but I can not directly from my host running 22.04. I can work with the VM's but I would rather not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'm curious to know whether or not you can connect to an already programmed board and get serial data in and out of it.

Comment: `all of these devices work fine with a windows` ... then your problem is with linux serial port ... nothing to do with Arduino ... you are asking at the wrong place

Comment: is it this problem? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/86211/fail-upload-sketches-to-esp8266-only-on-ubunto-20-04-3/86214#86214

Comment: @timemage - I had the same issue will 4 esp8266's all had code running on them. The issue ended up being a conflict or something with the CP210x driver. I found this solution in a separate post - it fixed my issue and I was able to replicate and validate this worked on a second 22.04 machine.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution in a separate post - it fixed my issue and I was able to replicate and validate this worked on a second 22.04 machine.

```
systemctl stop brltty-udev.service
sudo systemctl mask brltty-udev.service
systemctl stop brltty.service
systemctl disable brltty.service
```